# jQuery mobile swipe works intermittently

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using jQuery mobile 1.3.2 and I have added hooks for the swipe event. For each swipe event I am sliding the note_container left/right. However the registration of the swipe event is intermittent/not responsive on Samsung Galaxy S3 (and other android devices) but works well on the iPhone. Any particular reason why?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Notoji</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            width = $('.note').first().width();

            $('.note_container').bind('swipeleft', swipe_note_left);
            $('.note_container').bind('swiperight', swipe_note_right);

            function swipe_note_left(){
                alert("left swiped");
                left_val = $('.note_container').offset().left;
                adjusted_left = left_val - width;
                $('.note_container').animate({left: adjusted_left, useTranslate3d:true}, 250);
            }

            function swipe_note_right(){
                alert('right swiped');
                left_val = $('.note_container').offset().left;
                adjusted_left = left_val + width;
                $('.note_container').animate({left: adjusted_left, useTranslate3d:true}, 250);
            }
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <div class="title"> Notoji</div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="content review">
            <div class="note_container">
                <div class="note">
                    <div class="note_text">Its my birthday, and I have treated myself to a very nice gift.</div>
                    <img class="sticker" src="/assets/sally/sally_04.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="note">
                    <div class="note_text">The rogue defender. Killer the wrestler bunny.</div>
                    <img class="sticker" src="/assets/killer/killer_01.png"/>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <a href="create.html" data-transition="slideup" data-inline="true">
                <span class="create"></span>
            </a>
            </span> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can test out the code here: http://jsbin.com/UPoparU/1/

Comment: It works just fine on Samsung Galaxy S3 and Nexus 7.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and have found that touchmove (or at least something related to touchmove) is causing the problem. Even the slightest up/down motion triggers page scrolling and for some reason cancels the swipe.

To quickly test if touchmove is the cause you can disable touchmove by doing this at the end of the body:

```
<script>
    $(document.body).on('touchmove', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

This makes swipes work very well for me, but of course it disables scrolling (and I need scrolling, so it is not a solution for me), but maybe you can do without scrolling? Or maybe figure out the specific bug or some other way of getting around it. Anyway I know this is not a proper solution, but I thought it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, using Jquery mobile and Cordova on a Galaxy S3. I ended up using this third party library and it cleared it up:

http://www.codingjack.com/playground/swipe/